# Memory usage keep increasing on continues looping with Runtime.exec()

Tags: memory-leaks, java-8, runtime.exec

I have an application where I am collecting (Linux) system information periodically ( every 1~2) minute using a system command. When I check on my process list (using `htop`), the memory usage percentage keep increasing. When the program start the percentage used was 0.5% and the next day when I check it was 1.4% in a server having 8GB of RAM. I can understand it is abnormal.

To illustrate the behavior I created the following snippet with fastest looping time and only the involved pieces of code. When I run I can see memory usage percentage is going up very fast (0.5% to 1.0% in less than 15 minutes)

```
    boolean done = false;
    //Process p = null;
    while (!done) {

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls /tmp");
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Done");

            // closing the opened filedescriptors/anything
            // p.destroy() // not helpful even  
            // then used the below,, still the same
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is it a memory leak or something else? Is there anything I am missing out here. Please guide me guys.

Comment: Why should a JVM bother cleaning up when 99% of the memory is still free? Your numbers imply that the example program can run for a day and still using only half of the memory, so why should it waste CPU cycles for garbage collection after only 15 minutes? And the numbers for the real server indicate even lesser need for preemptive cleanup. Is your primary goal having as much unused memory as possible?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My point about the CPU usage is not for the whole system. It is for only the above mentioned program.

Comment: I don’t understand what you comment is heading at. If memory usage raises from 0.5% to 1.4% on an 8GB system, it means that the application uses 74MB more memory. After a day. I would understand that you are alarmed, if you say that the JVM has been configured to use at most 80MB, but that would be an important information that shouldn’t be omitted from the question. Without that, I assume that no limit has been configured for the JVM’s heap and 0.9% are exactly that, just 0.9%. A ridiculously small fraction.

Comment: The above information I gathered from the testing server. What I am worried was when I was running the program in a Linux box with 1.5G RAM in which almose 1.2 G RAM was used by the other processes. Any way, the only point I want to make sure here is, there is no any memory leak and the JVM will release the memory which it is holding, when the system needs it.

Comment: You can’t draw conclusions about the presence or absence of memory leaks just be looking at the memory usage. Well, if the used memory drops down to a previous value, it suggests that all objects created in-between have been collected, but even that’s not for sure and such complete collection scenario is rather rare. You have to look at a heap dump to find out whether particular objects are still reachable. At best, combined with forcing an `OutOfMemoryError`. A JVM might keep unused objects in memory when there is no pressure, but it will free them before raising an error, if possible.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into VisualVM and try to make a heap dump and will analyze.

Comment: This post is old enough. solution might have been already found. But I think what @BlueBird wanted to do is setting JVM max memory size. If so, pass -Xmx and  -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize to JVM. Java memory management is controlled by GC. And developer should not control GC directly.